# How can i map to an object that has two fields of the same entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring MVC app i have the following `User` entity (stripped down for brevity):

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

And the following `Application` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String type;
    private String summary;
}
```

I would like to extend the `Application` entity to have a submitter (the applicant) and an approver (who the application is assigned to for approval) of type `User`:

```
@Entity
public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String type;
    private String summary;

    private User submitter;
    private User approver;
}
```

And the corresponding extended `User` entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    private Set<Application> applications;
}
```

An `Application` can have one submitter and one approver, but a `User` can have multiple applications either submitted or waiting for their approval, so i guess it's a `@OneToMany` relationship from the user's side.

This means the mapping on the `Application` side would look something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String type;
    private String summary;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User submitter;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User approver;
}
```

But what mapping do i use on the `User` side of the relationship?
I suppose it should be something like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = {"approver", "submitter"})
private Set<Application> applications;
```

But referencing multiple columns with `mappedBy` is not possible as far as i know.

I'm not even sure if my approach is right. Maybe i should have two separate fields in the `User` entity for the applications?

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to map it in the user... Does it really have to be a bi-directional relationship? Is the user without the applications not a valid user? I would simply write a query to obtain the 2 lists instead of trying to access it through the user. So in short, don't map it on the user side.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your comment. I'm quite new to JPA. According to [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) blog post, a bidirectional mapping is more efficient than an unidirectional one, that's why i though i should map them in a similar manner.

Comment: You shouldn't only be concerned about performance if that becomes a real issue. Do you really need all the applications when you load a user? Probably not. In the same blog Vlad states *many times, you are better off replacing collections with a query,*. And also in your case you aren't inserting users in the same transaction (I assume) as those already exist. Model your entities/domain like you want and test for performance.

Comment: @M.Deinum I guess you're right, thank you. I'll try and implement it in an unidirectional manner then.

Answer (score 1):

With your current mapping, you have only one reference from Application to user, the "user_id". This means, that currently submitter and approver is always identical, which I think is not what you want.

On the table to which your Application entity maps, you need two different columns. They need different names and should be mapped similar to this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id_submitter")
private User submitter;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id_approver")
private User approver;
```

On your User entity, you can then map two different @OneToMany relationships, e.g. like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "approver")
private Set<Application> applicationsApproved;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "submitter")
private Set<Application> applicationsSubmitted;
```

If you need a combined list, feel free to provide a method which combines the two lists:

```
public Set<Application> getApplications() {
    Set<Application> allApplications = new HashSet<>();
    allApplications.addAll(applicationsSubmitted);
    allApplications.addAll(applicationsApproved);
    return allApplications;
}
```

(please note: the combined List can of course only be used as read-only and cannot be written to and updated to the database, since it is a combination)